# Ruby on Rails - How to update using checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The title may be too general, but I hope someone can help me.

The scenario is the following:
- I have a model Types, TypesActivity and Activity (and the relation is many to many)
- After create the type (that only consists of a name), I then have to assign activities to that type and in order to do that I have in another view (form) 2 sections: 
   1) With a select_tag of the types (that shows the name)
   2) A list of checkboxes that display all of the activities

I'm showing the checkboxes using this on the form view

_form.html.erb

```
<% @activities.each do |a|%>
          <li><%= check_box_tag "act[]", a.id, false%> | <%= a.name%></li>
<%end%>
```

and in my controller

```
def create
  params[:act].each do |a|
    TypeActivity.create({:type_id => params[:resource][:type_id], :activity_id=>a})
  end

  redirect_to "somewhere"
end
```

And everything works fine, but I have a question about... how to update it?

Is this correct? (or is there another better way?)

```
def update
   _v = TypeActivity.find(params[:id]).type_id
   params[:act] do |a|
      TypeActivity.update_attributes(:type_id=>_v,:activity_id=>a)
   end
end
```

Also if I want to edit one TypeActivity (type_activities/edit/3) I wanted to show the checkboxes that were already selected, and I've done this

```
def edit
   @t = TypeActivity.find(params[:id]).type_id
   @activities = Activity.all
end
```

and in my view

_form.html.erb

```
<% @activities.each do |a|%>
  <li><%= check_box_tag "act[]", a.id, !TypeActivity.where(:type_id=>@t,:activity_id=>a.id).empty?%> | <%= a.name%></li>
<%end%>
```

Is that a good way?

Thanks in advance to everyone that read all of it =)

JavierQQ

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263333/update-values-of-checkbox-with-habtm-relationship-rails. 

Please go and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If the `type_activity` table **only** contains `type_id` and `activity_id` then you are better off not creating a `TypeActivty` model at all.

Treat `type_activity` as a link table and configure a **has_and_belongs_to_many association** in the `Type` and `Activity` models.  Then use the `TypesController` to manage the assignment of Activities to a Type.

#### Reading Materials

Rails Guide on associations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Railscast #17 - HABTM Checkboxes:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes